# Unmarshalling a JSON object with JSON array into a struct

Tags: json, go

I want to unmarshal an array of json object into a struct.  Each json object has a json array for one of the properties. If the property is defined as a string, works.  If it's defined as an array of byte or string, I get an error.

I have tried a number of approaches but keep getting an error.

```
panic: ERROR: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field 
.productlist of type []string
```

Source file:

```
{
  "orgs": [
    {
      "orgname": "Test Organization 26",
      "orgs_id": 26,
      "contactdate": "2019-12-12",
      "sincedate": "2019-12-12",
      "estusers": null,
      "estvehicles": null,
      "paidusers": null,
      "paythreshold": null,
      "productlist": "[\"SDCC\",\"JOB_CARDS\",\"ALLOCATIONS\"]",
      "roles": "[\"DISPATCH\",\"DRIVERS\",\"MECHANICS\"]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Go Struct:

```
type OrgsJSONData struct {
    Orgs []struct {
        Orgname      string      `json:"orgname"`
        OrgsID       int         `json:"orgs_id"`
        Contactdate  string      `json:"contactdate"`
        Sincedate    string      `json:"sincedate"`
        Estusers     interface{} `json:"estusers"`
        Estvehicles  interface{} `json:"estvehicles"`
        Paidusers    interface{} `json:"paidusers"`
        Paythreshold interface{} `json:"paythreshold"`
        Productlist  []string    `json:"productlist"`
        Roles        string      `json:"roles"`
    } `json:"orgs"`
}
```

Code:

```
    var orgsJSONData OrgsJSONData
    tmp := []byte(strings.Join(JsonData, ""))
    err := json.Unmarshal(tmp, &orgsJSONData)
    if err != nil {
        panic("ERROR: " + err.Error())
    }
```

If the productlist property is a string, the unmarshal works.  If it is any other slice or array, I get the error "panic: ERROR: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field .productlist of type []string"  What am I doing wrong.  P.S. Very new to Golang (Week 2 and learning)

Comment: As stated by bserdar in the answer `productlist` is a string not an array, so you can either declare the `Productlist` field as `string`, just like you're doing with `Roles`, or you can define a custom slice type that implements the `json.Unmarshaler` interface and unmarshals the string as an array.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/Jn3yQU6HJSf

Comment: Thank you - The issue was right in front of me and I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 5):

The productlist field in the JSON input is a string, not an array:

```
"productlist": "[\"SDCC\",\"JOB_CARDS\",\"ALLOCATIONS\"]"
```

Note that the contents of it are quoted, and enclosed quotes are escaped. This is a string, not an array.

If it was an array, it would have been:

```
"productlist": ["SDCC","JOB_CARDS","ALLOCATIONS"]
```